# Why GNOME HIG discourags GTK_BUTTONS_OK?

Tags: gtk

In GTK+'s official reference, the [GtkMessageDialog page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.11/GtkMessageDialog.html#GtkButtonsType), it says,

> Note Please note that `GTK_BUTTONS_OK`, `GTK_BUTTONS_YES_NO` and
>   `GTK_BUTTONS_OK_CANCEL` are discouraged by the [GNOME HIG](http://library.gnome.org/devel/hig-book/stable/).

I read the latest version of GNOME HIG and found [this page](https://developer.gnome.org/hig-book/3.10/windows-alert.html.en#alert-button-order).

> Place the affirmative button in the **lower right
>   corner** of the alert.
>
> If the alert was produced in response to a user's
>   action, place a Cancel button immediately **to the left** of the
>   affirmative button.

I can figure out why `GTK_BUTTONS_YES_NO` and `GTK_BUTTONS_OK_CANCEL` are discouraged(because the negitive button is to the right of the affirmative one). But this has nothing to do with just one OK button on the dialog window. So, why `GTK_BUTTONS_OK` is discouraged?

And sorry about the title. I didn't actually see GNOME HIG discourages it.

Answer (score 3):

On the very same page you linked to:

> **Button Phrasing**
>
> Write button labels as imperative verbs, for example Save, Print. This
>   allows users to select an action with less hesitation. An active
>   phrase also fits best with the button's role in initiating actions, as
>   contrasted with a more passive phrase. For example Find and Log In are
>   better buttons than Yes and OK.

This is for your Yes/No and OK/Cancel point.

Comment: So this is the real reason for not using Yes/No and OK/Cancel. I should use Exit/Stay rather than Yes/No in the _Do you really want to exit?_ dialog. But what if I just want to tell the user that _All updates are complete._, like the start of the page I linked to? I can't imagine a more proper reaction than _OK_ from the user after the read this message.

Comment: dont use "are you sure you want to exit" dialogs unless the user may lose data by exiting (and even in that case auto saving is more forgiving and useful). don't use a dialog to notify the completeness of the operation; there's the InfoBar widget, for one, but you can also design your UI so that the completeness of a task is obvious.